# Why calls with nested generic type has worse performance in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, generics

I've encountered interesting case while implementing allocation-free Linq. The benchmark time suddenly increased when I changed code little bit, and I thought the change was trivial. I narrowed it down to this test code:

```cs
    [Benchmark]
    public int ComparingGenericArgument1()
    {
        var comparer = new Wrap<int>(Comparer<int>.Default);
        return CompareSum<Wrap<int>>.Calc(10000, comparer);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int ComparingGenericArgument2()
    {
        var comparer = new Wrap<int, Comparer<int>>(Comparer<int>.Default);
        return CompareSum<Wrap<int, Comparer<int>>>.Calc(10000, comparer);
    }

    static class CompareSum<TComparer> where TComparer : struct, IComparer<int>
    {
        public static int Calc(int count, TComparer comparer)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                sum += comparer.Compare(i, j);

            return sum;
        }
    }

    struct Wrap<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        IComparer<T> comparer;

        public Wrap(IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }

        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return comparer.Compare(x, y);
        }
    }

    struct Wrap<T, TComparer> : IComparer<T>
        where TComparer : IComparer<T>
    {
        TComparer comparer;

        public Wrap(TComparer comparer)
        {
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }

        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return comparer.Compare(x, y);
        }
    }
```

When I run the benchmark above, the result is like this:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.2, OS=Windows 10 (10.0.19043.2130/21H1/May2021Update)
AMD Ryzen 5 3600, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.101
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.1 (6.0.121.56705), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.1 (6.0.121.56705), X64 RyuJIT AVX2


|                    Method |     Mean |   Error |  StdDev | Allocated |
|-------------------------- |---------:|--------:|--------:|----------:|
| ComparingGenericArgument1 | 254.2 ms | 3.72 ms | 3.29 ms |    1804 B |
| ComparingGenericArgument2 | 458.0 ms | 5.04 ms | 4.71 ms |     480 B |
```

It almost doubled out. What?

When I directly call either `Wrap<T>` or `Wrap<T1, T2>`, the performance is equal. But when I have wrapper class that makes it nested generic, the performance is suddenly getting dropped. The performance drop persisted for both `Comparer<int>` and `IComparer<int>`.

I put the code to SharpLab to inspect assembly generated and the nested generic version obviously makes it much larger. But I am no assembly expert so couldn't get enough insight. This is result of simplified version, `return comparer.CompareTo(0, count)`:

```
C+CompareSum`1[[C+Wrap`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib]], _]].Calc(Int32, Wrap`1<Int32>)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: push ecx
    L0004: mov ecx, [ebp+8]
    L0007: xor edx, edx
    L0009: call dword ptr [0x10d87008]
    L000f: pop ebp
    L0010: ret 4

C+CompareSum`1[[C+Wrap`2[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], _]].Calc(Int32, Wrap`2<Int32,System.__Canon>)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: push esi
    L0004: push eax
    L0005: mov [ebp-8], edx
    L0008: mov esi, ecx
    L000a: mov ecx, [edx+0x20]
    L000d: mov ecx, [ecx]
    L000f: mov eax, [ecx+8]
    L0012: test eax, eax
    L0014: je short L0018
    L0016: jmp short L0024
    L0018: mov ecx, edx
    L001a: mov edx, 0x10d8d530
    L001f: call 0x0f429aa0
    L0024: push esi
    L0025: lea ecx, [ebp+8]
    L0028: xor edx, edx
    L002a: call eax
    L002c: pop ecx
    L002d: pop esi
    L002e: pop ebp
    L002f: ret 4
```

So, what is making this big difference when I use nested generic type? I would appreciate some knowledge share. Thank you!

Comment: This seems related. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67065306/3133823

Answer (score 3):

The issue is called by the generic implementation of:

```
static class CompareSum<TComparer> where TComparer : struct, IComparer<int>
{
    public static int Calc(int count, TComparer comparer)
```

This definition causes the following IL to be generated:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    int32 Calc (
        int32 count,
        !TComparer comparer
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20d0
    // Code size 46 (0x2e)
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 sum,
        [1] int32 i,
        [2] int32 j
    )

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0001: stloc.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0003: stloc.1
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0004: br.s IL_0028
    // loop start (head: IL_0028)
        IL_0006: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0007: stloc.2
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0008: br.s IL_0020
        // loop start (head: IL_0020)
            IL_000a: ldloc.0
            IL_000b: ldarga.s comparer
            IL_000d: ldloc.1
            IL_000e: ldloc.2
            IL_000f: constrained. !TComparer
            IL_0015: callvirt instance int32 class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`1<int32>::Compare(!0, !0)
            IL_001a: add
            IL_001b: stloc.0
            IL_001c: ldloc.2
            IL_001d: ldc.i4.1
            IL_001e: add
            IL_001f: stloc.2

            IL_0020: ldloc.2
            IL_0021: ldarg.0
            IL_0022: blt.s IL_000a
        // end loop

        IL_0024: ldloc.1
        IL_0025: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0026: add
        IL_0027: stloc.1

        IL_0028: ldloc.1
        IL_0029: ldarg.0
        IL_002a: blt.s IL_0006
    // end loop

    IL_002c: ldloc.0
    IL_002d: ret
} // end of method CompareSum`1::Calc
```

with the critical instructions being:

```
IL_000f: constrained. !TComparer
IL_0015: callvirt instance int32 class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`1<int32>::Compare(!0, !0)
```

the `constrained` instruction has some very interesting [behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> When a callvirt method instruction has been prefixed by constrained
> thisType, the instruction is executed as follows:
>
> - If thisType is a reference type (as opposed to a value type) then ptr
>   is dereferenced and passed as the 'this' pointer to the callvirt of
>   method.
> - If thisType is a value type and thisType implements method then ptr is
>   passed unmodified as the 'this' pointer to a call method instruction,
>   for the implementation of method by thisType.
> - If thisType is a value type and thisType does not implement method
>   then ptr is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the 'this' pointer to
>   the callvirt method instruction.

In the first case (`Wrap<T>`), it seems that the lack of an additional reference type parameter causes the second bullet point to occur and the pointer is passed unmodified.

In the second case (`Wrap<T, TComparer>`), it seems to invoke bullet point three, causing boxing and performance regressions.

Interestingly enough, if you change the implementation to the following:

```
static class CompareSum<TComparer> where TComparer : struct, IComparer<int>
{
    public static int Calc(int count, IComparer<int> comparer)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                sum += comparer.Compare(i, j);

        return sum;
    }
}
```

the constrained call disappears, although performance is then bad for *both* cases, due to boxing when calling Calc.

If instead `TComparer` is cast to `Compare<int>` instead of the interface abstraction, there is no longer ambiguity about if `TCompare` is a reference type or value type and the `constrained` instruction disappears:

```
class CompareSum<TComparer> where TComparer : struct, IComparer<int>
{
    public static int Calc(int count, TComparer comparer)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        Comparer<int> castComparer = Unsafe.As<TComparer, Comparer<int>>(ref comparer);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                sum += castComparer.Compare(i, j);

        return sum;
    }
}
```

This results in the following IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    int32 Calc (
        int32 count,
        !TComparer comparer
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20d0
    // Code size 48 (0x30)
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 sum,
        [1] class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1<int32> castComparer,
        [2] int32 i,
        [3] int32 j
    )

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0001: stloc.0
    IL_0002: ldarga.s comparer
    IL_0004: call !!1& [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe::As<!TComparer, class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1<int32>>(!!0&)
    IL_0009: ldind.ref
    IL_000a: stloc.1
    IL_000b: ldc.i4.0
    IL_000c: stloc.2
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_000d: br.s IL_002a
    // loop start (head: IL_002a)
        IL_000f: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0010: stloc.3
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0011: br.s IL_0022
        // loop start (head: IL_0022)
            IL_0013: ldloc.0
            IL_0014: ldloc.1
            IL_0015: ldloc.2
            IL_0016: ldloc.3
            IL_0017: callvirt instance int32 class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1<int32>::Compare(!0, !0)
            IL_001c: add
            IL_001d: stloc.0
            IL_001e: ldloc.3
            IL_001f: ldc.i4.1
            IL_0020: add
            IL_0021: stloc.3

            IL_0022: ldloc.3
            IL_0023: ldarg.0
            IL_0024: blt.s IL_0013
        // end loop

        IL_0026: ldloc.2
        IL_0027: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0028: add
        IL_0029: stloc.2

        IL_002a: ldloc.2
        IL_002b: ldarg.0
        IL_002c: blt.s IL_000f
    // end loop

    IL_002e: ldloc.0
    IL_002f: ret
} // end of method CompareSum`1::Calc

} // end of class CompareSum`1
```

Note that now the IL no longer contains the `constrained` instruction and in a benchmark, performance is nearly even.

---

An additional way to solve this is to no longer use a generic constraint on your class, but use explicit methods that take `Wrap` struct implementations. This has the same effect of bypassing the interface dispatch:

```
static class CompareSum
{
    public static int Calc(int count, Wrap<int> comparer)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                sum += comparer.Compare(i, j);

        return sum;
    }

    public static int Calc(int count, Wrap<int, Comparer<int>> comparer)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
                sum += comparer.Compare(i, j);

        return sum;
    }
}
```

This completely removes the `constrained` IL and foregoes boxing, bringing your implementations back into alignment. As an added benefit, it simplifies the call for your benchmarks:

```
[Benchmark]
public int ComparingGenericArgument1()
{
    var comparer = new Wrap<int>(Comparer<int>.Default);
    return CompareSum.Calc(10000, comparer);
}

[Benchmark]
public int ComparingGenericArgument2()
{
    var comparer = new Wrap<int, Comparer<int>>(Comparer<int>.Default);
    return CompareSum.Calc(10000, comparer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue! Though I want to point out `Wrap<T, TComparer>` also directly implements `IComparer<T>`, so I was expecting it to behave same as when calling `Wrap<T>`. Do you think it would still be boxed?

Comment: @cathei that is my best guess, although the open generic-ness of `CompareSum` makes it so that SharpLab/Linqpad can't correctly show the JIT ASM.

Comment: I used `[JitGeneric]` attribute to generate jitasm. It turned out when I put `Wrap<*Any class*>` it creates longer version. If I put `Wrap<*Any value type*>` then I get same short version as `Wrap<int>`. But if I make `Wrap<T>` as class, it doesn't happen! So it is something that happen when use reference type generic argument to value type. Interesting.

Comment: @cathei ahh, I think that is the other piece of the puzzle. Looking at the IL for `Wrap<T>` vs `Wrap<T, TComparer>`, there are additional instructions and, most importantly, another `constrained` instruction. However, I don't think that is what is causing the slowness, since if you invoke both methods Wrap methods directly, the performance is fine, or at least very close. It is definitely centric to Calc.

Comment: I made a better example and questioned on dotnet repository, if you are interested :) https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/77192

Comment: @cathei I am convinced that the issue is caused by interface dispatch and internal casts because of the `constrained` instruction. I've updated my answer with additional details. I am also very curious to see what the response is on your opened issue :).